# WYSIWYG html editor query

Tags: html, editor, wysiwyg, mshtml, ihtmldocument2

I am in the process of creating a simple WYSIWYG HTML editor to enable the users of my application to design simple HTML emails.

At the moment I have decided to use the web browser control with MSHTML to enable me to edit what is displayed. I have a tool bar which holds all of the relevant buttons, bold, underline, etc.

I need a way to check if the current block has any formatting so the correct state can be displayed on the buttons in the tool bar. I tried to add an event handler to the IHTMLDocument to fire when the mouse is moved or the arrow keys are pressed, however, this stopped the web browser from taking any input.

Is there a simpler way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel, there are millions of ready made WYSIWYG editors for the web, why not use one of those instead and use your time for something meaningful?

Comment: While I find it a honourable thing to try and program something like that by yourself, I have to agree with Tatu here. The ready-made WYSIWYG editors provide functions to easily fetch the current selection/HTML element, and probe it for things like style, size and so on. Plus, they already have the formatting stuff implemented. On the other hand, if you want to do it yourself and don't get any help here, you can look at how the WYSIWYG editors do it. CKEditor for example is split nicely into plugins, and you may be able to follow through from the "bold button" plugin down to the system call.

Answer (score 0):

There are several rich editors for free out of that tinyMCE is one of the better editor.

For list of editors see the link below.

http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors