# Best RichTextbox control editor for asp.net

Tags: asp.net, textbox

I am looking for Best Textbox control editor for asp.net

I came across this website
http://www.asp.net/community/projects#jm_starter_kits_and_samples

And there are around 4 open source.

Can anyone suggest which one is best to use?

1) FreeTextbox

2) MarkDownSharp

3) TinyMCE

4) CKEditor.

Incase you know better that one listed please inform using link.

Thanks

Comment: THE MOST common question at stackoverflow:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98852/wysiwyg-text-editor-for-webpage 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/84353/i-need-a-wysiwyg-web-editor-web-based

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5833/looking-for-wysiwyg-html-editor

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604311/wysiwyg-browser-editor-that-generates-good-html

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805639/javascript-wysiwyg-html-editors

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020049/wysiwyg-html-editor-query

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441521/lightest-wysiwyg-javascript-editor

Answer (score 1):

TinyMCE and CKEditor would be my top two choices. I think you'd be splitting hairs between them.